# Use Google maps without publish

Tags: android, google-maps

One of my clients want use application without publishing it to google play store. This application use Google Maps. On some phone models map is working fine with debug apk, but on others map is blank.
I thought that generation of signed apk and use new api key for signing keystore will solve the problem. But when I'm installing signed apk file even on my phone, map is blank. This is because application needs to be published in Google Play store?

Comment: No, Google Maps has nothing to do with the Play Store.  Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Check your `Map API key`..

Answer (score 0):

No, [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) can be used even in debug mode, so it has nothing to do with  [APK signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).
Since you say it depends on phone model you debug on, maybe it could be a problem with screen resolution/size and your [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Replace the SHA1 key according your Keystore file Map will work properly. And Steps for get SHA1 key from Keystore file of Application.
->Right click on Project.
->Click on Export Option.
->Select Android Application and Press next.
->Select Existing Key Store file which you have created.
->Enter keystore password and press next.
->Select your alias and enter password and and press next.
->And Now you will get SHA1 Key in below part of Wizard and mention in Attached screenshot.
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using terminal command keytool -list -v -keystore "sajacargoclient2.jks" In console I have this: http://i62.tinypic.com/2872ade.png one is for debug (and it's working only on several phones) others two are for release keystores and not working. Maybe I have too old google play services? In gradle I have 4.2.+

Comment: You have change SHA1 key in google Map Api V2 because of Security Purpose and recognize the app. Just get sHA1 key from Keystore of your sign build and replace with existing key in Google Map api V2. It will work. I am sure.